# Simplifications and error in matrix integral operator

Tags: matrix, operators

I defined the matrix integral operator

```
\[ScriptCapitalD]11[w_] := (1/2)*D[w[x], x] - 
r[x]*Integrate[q[x]*w[x], x]
\[ScriptCapitalD]12[w_] := r[x]*Integrate[r[x]*w[x], x]
\[ScriptCapitalD]21[w_] := (-q[x])*Integrate[q[x]*w[x], x]
\[ScriptCapitalD]22[w_] := (-2^(-1))*D[w[x], x] + 
q[x]*Integrate[r[x]*w[x], x]
m = {{\[ScriptCapitalD]11, \[ScriptCapitalD]12}, {\[ScriptCapitalD]21, \[ScriptCapitalD]22}};
```

and defined how it acts in a column vector

```
operate[matrix_, column_] := 
Table[Inner[#1[#2] & , \[Mu], column, Plus], 
{\[Mu], matrix}]
```

Code result is

```
result = operate[m, {r[x], q[x]}]; 
MatrixForm[FullSimplify[result]]
```

How can I further simplify the vanishing integrals? (see image below). What I am doing wrong that I obtain the correct result up to a factor of $2$?

[image]

Comment: Note how you get nonsense things like `q[x][x]` in your integrals. Try `operate[m, {r, q}]` instead.

Comment: That solution worked, but don't know why. Sorry the trivial question, but what if, instead of your suggestion, I put an explicit function to operate?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. `r` is a function. `r[x]` is not a function, but a function called with an argument. If you want to be super explicit about calling `operate` with functions, you could use `operate[m, {Function[x, r[x]], Function[x, q[x]]}]`.